# Data model to store a report with lots of question and answer type data

Tags: database-design

I have to design the model to store a report which contains many sections. Each section contains a set of questions and answers and a few tables of data.

I have taken a few design decisions and wanted to validate whether I am on the right track:

1. I have not stored any reference to sections in the data model. Is this good or Should I store the references to document sections in the DB? I thought of handling this at application level.
2. I have created each question as a column as opposed to designing a generic question and answer model. In fact, I created a generic question and answer model - but decided against using it as the requirements are mostly known and there would be some minimal changes. The question text can be handled by the application layer and only the answers are stored in DB - I need some opinions on whether what I have done here is a good practice.
3. Is is a good idea to create an entity for each logical grouping of attributes/questions? The principle I follow is to create an entity for repeating groups of attributes. For non-repeating attributes, I am creating all of them directly under overall report entity and it leads to lots of attributes in that entity. I am not sure whether it is a good or bad thing from a DB design perspective. If I have to create entities to store a related group of attributes, then I can just have a FK to that entity and it would look more elegant on the model, but there is a join involved - which approach is better here and how do I decide on one vs the other?

Comment: I probably wouldn't store each question/answer as a column. You're making it hard to add/subtract questions and also storing empty data for unanswered/unasked questions.

Comment: Agreed with Matthew PK.  Storing each Q/A as a column just leads to sparsely populated tables and runs the risk of making your records too big to be accessed efficiently.  Depending on how long your answers are allowed to be, you could hit a practical limit quickly.

Comment: @Matthew, @Joel - thanks for your comments. On thinking about this further, I also came to the same conclusion that you both suggested. Do you have any thoughts on my point no.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done.

I have designed a generic Question & Answer model which can support any number of questions and any combination of them in any report.